# Rails render_async gem with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

did someone succeeded to use render_async gem with rails 6 app on webpacker?

Actually JS callback is never called for me

Comment: Why would you need that gem with webpacker? If you're using webpacker, you're surely using JavaScript which is an async language.

Comment: @ZedTuX because it has a lot of cool methods to add ajax with rails syntax